# WIF10201: No valid key mapping found for securityToken: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' - Signing key rollover working a expected

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

We are developing an app that had worked perfectly until last night.  We had already checked this app out and several other ones that we are developing back in August 2016 to address the signing key rollover mentioned here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#how-to-perform-a-manual-rollover-if-you-application-does-not-support-automatic-rollover

All was good.  now we can't get this app to get to the ReplyURL anymore.  This is happening on 2 separate development machines.  I've tried everything I can to resolve this, but have run out of ideas.   Using VS 2013 Pro

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  All of the articles I'm finding are from 2014 and are related to Microsoft getting a new certificate because their old one was due to expire.  The resolutions from those articles don't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with VS2013 Pro.

I used my trusty thumb drive to move the solution directory onto another development machine that had VS2015 on it, opened the solution, hit publish, and it worked fine.  Old articles that I was reading said that everything starting with VS2013 should be able to update security keys automatically, but it seems that is no longer the case.

If you have no access to VS2015, there are some scripts here that may be able to help you manually update: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-powershell-tokenkey